# Is there a way to remove ember-data from emberfire?

Tags: firebase, ember.js, emberfire, ember-octane

My app does not use `ember-data`, it uses only apollo for graphql to retrieve/manage data.

But after installing `emberfire`, we must have to install `ember-data` too.
We just use `emberfire/firebase` for authentication :)

If I try to remove it I've got an error:

```
Cannot find module 'ember-data/package.json' from '/Users/bruno/octane-graphql/node_modules/emberfire'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution here is simple: don't use emberfire!

Basically the entire concept of emberfire is to intergrate firebase into ember-data. If you just want to use some firebase services use the firebase sdk directly.

Comment: Nice, I will try to implement the auth service + ESA myself. Thanks! :D

Answer (score 1):

emberfire uses ember-data under the hood. So you need to have it installed.

Comment: Yeah, I think it could be optional for some cases, but as Lux says, the best option is to remove it :D Thanks anyway!

Comment: We are saying the same thing. I'm not saying ember-data could be optional, but rather that if you use emberfire, you must have ember-data installed. Whether you remove emberfire or not is completely up to you, and not the answer to your original question.